# Alterar tema padrão bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia, estou estudando o Bootstrap e gostaria de alterar o tema padrão do mesmo.
Tenho a seguinte navBar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quero que ela fique com o seguinte formato:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que tenho que alterar o tema padrão em custom-theme.scss, sei que dá pra fazer direto no CSS mas como estou estudando o Bootstrap, queria saber como alterar o tema padrão.
Grato.

Comment: Pelo que eu saiba você só altera o tema padrão do Bootstrap alterando o css dele mesmo como você disse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

Esse é o CSS default do Bootstrap 4 https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css

Mas vamos supor que vc queira trocar a cor primária para roxo por exemplo. Vc vai precisar entra nesse link com o `.css` oficial, da um `Ctrl+F` e pesquisa pelo nome da classe que deseja `--primary`.

```
:root {
  --primary: #007bff;
}
```

Copia esses estilos, cria um arquivo `.css` novo e cola esses estilo no `.css` por exemplo `override.css` e salva seu arquivo na pasta dos css, depois vc indexa esse arquivo `.css` após o css do Bootstrap para fazer a sobreposição da classe, ou se não for usar o `.css` do Bootstrap indexe apenas o seu `override.css` dentro da tag `<head>` do seu documento dessa forma

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/override.css">
</head>
<div class="row">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
```

O ideal é que vc não altere as classes originais do Bootstrap. Crie o seu próprio .CSS e dentro dele vai sobrescrevendo as coisa que gostaria de mudar.

Veja um exemplo mudando o fundo da `NavBar`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    .bg-light {
        background-color: #8a2be2 !important;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Repare que eu apenas precisei mudar o valor da classe `.bg-light` para o roxo e pronto, mas como dito não faça isso no arquivo original, faça isso no override.***